Track event and azure monitor
I need to add some metrics and want to analyze those metrics. I am using trackevent to pass the event to azure monitoring. I am following below page: -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics
I am using below code to generate event and sent it to azure monitor (application insights).
var telemetryConfig = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
_telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfig);
_telemetryClient.TrackEvent(eventName: "ResourceCreated",
                    properties: new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {"ParentID", "ResourceID"},
                        {"ResourceAction", "Action"}
                });

Is this sufficient to see the event on azure monitor or I need to do something more.
I don't see events on azure monitor.

Please provide how you specify connection string, which language you use, which type of app (console, web app).

(based on offline conversation - there wasn't Application Insights resource created)
Here what's needed to make above code to work:

Create Application Insights resource

Set connection string on telemetry configuration
telemetryConfig.ConnectionString = "Your Application Insights Connection String";

If this is console app then it is important to flush telemetry before exiting (at the same time, this should not be done for web apps as a part of processing requests)


